# Жарко́е: fried or roasted?

Tags: значения

According to Ozhegov dictionary, Жарко́е is

> Жареное кушанье, обычно мясное.

As Жареное can mean both fried or roasted, this definition is somewhat ambiguous. The Oxford Russian Dictionary translates Жарко́е as fried meat, but Russian wikipedia article about Жарко́е says that it is

> Блюдо из какой-либо части животного (без разделки на куски), запечённой в духовом шкафу или в русской печи.

Therefore we have two conflicting sources: fried (according to the Oxford Russian Dictionary) or roasted (запеченнoe, according to Russian Wikipedia).

Which is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not really comment on etymology of "жаркое", non-sourced version in Wikipedia

> "Название связано не с термином «жаренье» а с существительным «жар»,
> «жара», поскольку блюдо приготавливается не на плите, а в самой печи,
> в её наибольшем жару"

makes sense to me.

Regarding the meaning of "жаркое", I again side with Wikipedia:

> В современной русской кухне словом «жаркое» часто называют блюдо,
> больше похожее на венгерский гуляш — мясо, тушённое с картофелем,
> другими овощами и специями после предварительной обжарки или без неё.
> Оно подается с большим количеством бульона и без дополнительного
> гарнира (часто — в горшочке)

So modern "жаркое" is essentially a "stew" - not "fried" or "roasted" meat.

[Жаркое - wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Comment: +1. Exactly. A stew.

Answer (score 1):

I would say 'жаркое' is the meat and potatoes baked in an oven. Sometimes potatoes are roasted in a frying pan but that's a variation on the classic dish.
According to Universal American, the verb 'to roast' means 'to eat (esp. meat) by prolonged exposure to heat in an oven or over a fire'. So it's more likely 'a roast'.